# How to remove HTML content from REST API response?

Tags: rest, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I have started to work with REST APIs - specifically JIRA REST APIs.
I'm using the API to get response to a JIRA query but the JSON response I am getting contains lot of HTML chunk inside it.

It is not clean enough as showcased [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+API+Example+-+Query+issues#JIRARESTAPIExample-Queryissues-Response)

How can I use it in such a way to get a proper JSON response?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the JSON block in your "here" link. Did you mean that as a demonstration of what was going wrong, or was it meant to be how you wanted it to appear? Please give us an example of exactly what the response looks like, as well as the URL and headers you are using to request it.

Answer (score 1):

I think, JIRA response in JSON format only if request is successful, if request has any error than it comes in HTML response. actually that html belongs to the JIRA's error page. So correct your request, you will not get any response in HTML fomat. :)